# Javascript Object Array to Json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How to transform an Object in a valid Json.

Here is the object.

```
 [
  {
    "ASIN": [
      "059035342X"
    ],
    "DetailPageURL": [
      "http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Book/dp/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
    ],
    "ItemLinks": [
      {
        "ItemLink": [
          {
            "Description": [
              "Technical Details"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Book/dp/tech-data/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Baby Registry"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Wedding Registry"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Wishlist"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Tell A Friend"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "All Customer Reviews"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/review/product/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "All Offers"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ItemAttributes": [
      {
        "Author": [
          "J.K. Rowling"
        ],
        "Binding": [
          "Paperback"
        ],
        "Brand": [
          "Scholastic Press"
        ],
        "Creator": [
          {
            "_": "Mary GrandPré",
            "$": {
              "Role": "Illustrator"
            }
          }
        ],
        "EAN": [
          "9780590353427"
        ],
        "EANList": [
          {
            "EANListElement": [
              "9780590353427",
              "9780439708180",
              "0038332166576",
              "0078073006991",
              "0000590353425"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Edition": [
          "1st"
        ],
        "Feature": [
          "super alle"
        ],
        "IsAutographed": [
          "0"
        ],
        "ISBN": [
          "0439708184"
        ],
        "IsMemorabilia": [
          "0"
        ],
        "ItemDimensions": [
          {
            "Height": [
              {
                "_": "39",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Length": [
              {
                "_": "291",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Weight": [
              {
                "_": "50",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Width": [
              {
                "_": "205",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Label": [
          "Scholastic"
        ],
        "Languages": [
          {
            "Language": [
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Unknown"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Original Language"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Dictionary"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Published"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ListPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "1099"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$10.99"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Manufacturer": [
          "Scholastic"
        ],
        "MPN": [
          "9780590353427"
        ],
        "NumberOfItems": [
          "1"
        ],
        "NumberOfPages": [
          "320"
        ],
        "PackageDimensions": [
          {
            "Height": [
              {
                "_": "90",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Length": [
              {
                "_": "760",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Weight": [
              {
                "_": "135",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Width": [
              {
                "_": "520",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "PackageQuantity": [
          "1"
        ],
        "PartNumber": [
          "9780590353427"
        ],
        "ProductGroup": [
          "Book"
        ],
        "ProductTypeName": [
          "ABIS_BOOK"
        ],
        "PublicationDate": [
          "1999-10-01"
        ],
        "Publisher": [
          "Scholastic"
        ],
        "ReleaseDate": [
          "1999-09-08"
        ],
        "Studio": [
          "Scholastic"
        ],
        "Title": [
          "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone (Book 1)"
        ],
        "UPC": [
          "038332166576"
        ],
        "UPCList": [
          {
            "UPCListElement": [
              "038332166576",
              "000590353425",
              "078073006991"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "OfferSummary": [
      {
        "LowestNewPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "457"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$4.57"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "LowestUsedPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "1"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$0.01"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "LowestCollectiblePrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "500"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$5.00"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "TotalNew": [
          "203"
        ],
        "TotalUsed": [
          "2662"
        ],
        "TotalCollectible": [
          "20"
        ],
        "TotalRefurbished": [
          "0"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Offers": [
      {
        "TotalOffers": [
          "1"
        ],
        "TotalOfferPages": [
          "1"
        ],
        "MoreOffersUrl": [
          "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"
        ],
        "Offer": [
          {
            "OfferAttributes": [
              {
                "Condition": [
                  "New"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "OfferListing": [
              {
                "OfferListingId": [
                  "WNC029AwLyV8FHKUQwFk53YpinaFWX5xiXj0ZqO2CwN5siRkxmyNTF%2B%2Fh0sprWvlJE%2FdBsSC0pAKOc8N1YC096p%2BOJkjfsOwCpeRozFLUgY%3D"
                ],
                "Price": [
                  {
                    "Amount": [
                      "659"
                    ],
                    "CurrencyCode": [
                      "USD"
                    ],
                    "FormattedPrice": [
                      "$6.59"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "AmountSaved": [
                  {
                    "Amount": [
                      "440"
                    ],
                    "CurrencyCode": [
                      "USD"
                    ],
                    "FormattedPrice": [
                      "$4.40"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "PercentageSaved": [
                  "40"
                ],
                "Availability": [
                  "Usually ships in 24 hours"
                ],
                "AvailabilityAttributes": [
                  {
                    "AvailabilityType": [
                      "now"
                    ],
                    "MinimumHours": [
                      "0"
                    ],
                    "MaximumHours": [
                      "0"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ASIN": [
      "0545162076"
    ],
    "DetailPageURL": [
      "http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Paperback-Box-Books/dp/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
    ],
    "ItemLinks": [
      {
        "ItemLink": [
          {
            "Description": [
              "Technical Details"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Paperback-Box-Books/dp/tech-data/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Baby Registry"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0545162076%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Wedding Registry"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0545162076%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Add To Wishlist"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0545162076%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "Tell A Friend"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "All Customer Reviews"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/review/product/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Description": [
              "All Offers"
            ],
            "URL": [
              "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ItemAttributes": [
      {
        "Author": [
          "J. K. Rowling"
        ],
        "Binding": [
          "Paperback"
        ],
        "Brand": [
          "Arthur A. Levine Books"
        ],
        "EAN": [
          "9780545162074"
        ],
        "EANList": [
          {
            "EANListElement": [
              "9780545162074"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Edition": [
          "Slp"
        ],
        "Feature": [
          "HARRY POTTER COLLECTION"
        ],
        "Format": [
          "Box set"
        ],
        "ISBN": [
          "0545162076"
        ],
        "IsEligibleForTradeIn": [
          "1"
        ],
        "ItemDimensions": [
          {
            "Height": [
              {
                "_": "222",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Length": [
              {
                "_": "339",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Weight": [
              {
                "_": "688",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Width": [
              {
                "_": "415",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Label": [
          "Arthur A. Levine Books"
        ],
        "Languages": [
          {
            "Language": [
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Unknown"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Original Language"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Dictionary"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": [
                  "English"
                ],
                "Type": [
                  "Published"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ListPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "8693"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$86.93"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Manufacturer": [
          "Arthur A. Levine Books"
        ],
        "MPN": [
          "9780545162074"
        ],
        "NumberOfItems": [
          "1"
        ],
        "NumberOfPages": [
          "7"
        ],
        "PackageDimensions": [
          {
            "Height": [
              {
                "_": "560",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Length": [
              {
                "_": "1050",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Weight": [
              {
                "_": "600",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Width": [
              {
                "_": "850",
                "$": {
                  "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "PackageQuantity": [
          "1"
        ],
        "PartNumber": [
          "9780545162074"
        ],
        "ProductGroup": [
          "Book"
        ],
        "ProductTypeName": [
          "ABIS_BOOK"
        ],
        "PublicationDate": [
          "2009-07-01"
        ],
        "Publisher": [
          "Arthur A. Levine Books"
        ],
        "ReleaseDate": [
          "2009-07-07"
        ],
        "Studio": [
          "Arthur A. Levine Books"
        ],
        "Title": [
          "Harry Potter Paperback Box Set (Books 1-7)"
        ],
        "TradeInValue": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "938"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$9.38"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "OfferSummary": [
      {
        "LowestNewPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "4386"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$43.86"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "LowestUsedPrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "3876"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$38.76"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "LowestCollectiblePrice": [
          {
            "Amount": [
              "13900"
            ],
            "CurrencyCode": [
              "USD"
            ],
            "FormattedPrice": [
              "$139.00"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "TotalNew": [
          "55"
        ],
        "TotalUsed": [
          "47"
        ],
        "TotalCollectible": [
          "2"
        ],
        "TotalRefurbished": [
          "0"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Offers": [
      {
        "TotalOffers": [
          "1"
        ],
        "TotalOfferPages": [
          "1"
        ],
        "MoreOffersUrl": [
          "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0545162076%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0545162076"
        ],
        "Offer": [
          {
            "OfferAttributes": [
              {
                "Condition": [
                  "New"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "OfferListing": [
              {
                "OfferListingId": [
                  "aDy%2F5hDjvnYM7TXwBw3JmACiV6Q%2FaF6ODwl34%2FyhsgTfQ9QOXpqdSjkdpBrgL6tODUNBf7l%2Bbg9cfsvKwWnVlpzq55Y6zFiIrEKvTPiVzBp%2FUUe2L4U%2B9w%3D%3D"
                ],
                "Price": [
                  {
                    "Amount": [
                      "4386"
                    ],
                    "CurrencyCode": [
                      "USD"
                    ],
                    "FormattedPrice": [
                      "$43.86"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "AmountSaved": [
                  {
                    "Amount": [
                      "4307"
                    ],
                    "CurrencyCode": [
                      "USD"
                    ],
                    "FormattedPrice": [
                      "$43.07"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "PercentageSaved": [
                  "50"
                ],
                "Availability": [
                  "Usually ships in 2 to 4 weeks"
                ],
                "AvailabilityAttributes": [
                  {
                    "AvailabilityType": [
                      "now"
                    ],
                    "MinimumHours": [
                      "360"
                    ],
                    "MaximumHours": [
                      "648"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
 }
```

Is it possible to transform it in a Json and how ?

With JSON.stringify i get something like that :

```
[{"ASIN":["059035342X"],"DetailPageURL":["http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Book/dp/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"],"ItemLinks":[{"ItemLink":[{"Description":["Technical Details"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Book/dp/tech-data/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["Add To Baby Registry"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["Add To Wedding Registry"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["Add To Wishlist"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D059035342X%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["Tell A Friend"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["All Customer Reviews"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/review/product/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]},{"Description":["All Offers"],"URL":["http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/059035342X%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIWQFMTXLQXV7SGXA%26tag%3D[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D059035342X"]}]}],"ItemAttributes":[{"Author":["J.K. Rowling"],"Binding":["Paperback"],"Brand":["Scholastic Press"]
```

This is my code :

Node js :

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', products: JSON.stringify(results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item) });
```

In Jade :

```
each item in products
                    li= item
```

The output is something like that.

```
<li>[</li><li>{</li><li>&quot;</li><li>A</li><li>S</li><li>I</li><li>N</li><li>&quot;</li><li>:</li><li>[</li><li>&quot;</li><li>0</li><li>5</li><li>9</li><li>0</li><li>3</li><li>5</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>2</li><li>X</li><li>&quot;</li><li>]</li><li>,</li><li>&quot;</li><li>D</li><li>e</li><li>t</li><li>a</li><li>i</li><li>l</li><li>P</li><li>a</li><li>g</li><li>e</li><li>U</li><li>R</li><li>L</li><li>&quot;</li><li>:</li><li>[</li><li>&quot;</li><li>h</li><li>t</li><li>t</li><li>p</li><li>:</li><li>/</li><li>/</li><li>w</li><li>w</li><li>w</li><li>.</li><li>a</li><li>m</li><li>a</li><li>z</li><li>o</li><li>n</li><li>.</li><li>c</li><li>o</li><li>m</li><li>/</li><li>H</li><li>a</li><li>r</li><li>r</li><li>y</li><li>
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: "I tried Json.Stringify but without success." — How? What did you try? What result did you get?

Comment: `Json.Stringify !== JSON.stringify`. But yes, 'without success' may mean anything.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` convert JSON to text, and `JSON.parse` convert text to JSON. Can i see your script that does the conversion? Not the result, but the script.

Comment: @Iqbal Fauzi   JSON.stringify convert a javascript object to a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's your purpose here, but if you want to iterate the array, than you don't need to convert it to JSON on your controller, it's already on JSON(object) format.

Try this :

node:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', products: results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item });
```

jade:

```
ul
  each item in products
    li= item.ASIN
```

Comment: That's what i did. But ( maybe i'l confusing), when i print an item i have [Object] instead of the content. So it's not a json

Comment: Look like you're confusing between `object` and `json`. Printing object type will not print the contents of the object, instead it will print `object` text. As I see on your example, `item` is an object ( that is also JSON ), and you can't print it directly to get the contents.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your code block. 
The last `}` should be a `]`. Mayby this is the source of your problem.

Other than that, creating a JSON string in Javascript is done using:

```
var x = /*....*/;
var json = JSON.stringify(x);
```

Comment: Sorry for the error in a code block. I cut it manually for not pasting everything.

Answer (score -1):

[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) can validate your JSON string and highlight syntax errors.

Comment: @IqbalFauzi - yeah, but I think someone that new can't make comments so they don't really have a choice if they want to contribute.